# Setup WebHDFS authentication

Tags: basic-authentication, webhdfs

I have setup a WebHDFS server with a self signed SSL certificate for testing. Now I need some kind of authentication on it where the user has to pass some credentials in the WebHDFS rest call. I am reading through https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html, and it seems like it only allows Kerberos or OAuth2 authentication. This is too complex for my needs. Is there a way I can configure basic authentication? If not, then is there any quick way to get some Kerberos or Oauth2 server up and running?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: WebHDFS does not exist out of thin air. It is a gateway to HDFS (or compatible stuff such as MaprFS / Ezmeral) and requires the same exact auth protocol that is used by the back-end. If your HDFS setup has no auth enforced, then ditto for WebHDFS.

Comment: What is your use case, at the core? Add some makeshift access control on top on a unsecured Hadoop cluster? Then just add a nginx proxy in front of the WebHDFS service, and configure the proxy to filter incoming calls with basic auth.

Comment: But if your target Hadoop setup requires Kerberos auth, you need to set up Kerberos in your test environment because it makes a MASSIVE difference to about everything. Prepare for hell.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. The use case is simple - use REST api to test different operations on HDFS data. All I need is to put some kind of auth on the api calls so that the user should need some credentials before doing anything on HDFS. The target Hadoop setup does not need auth at the moment, but I can change it - I checked here https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.4/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml, and I don't see anything to setup a simple basic auth. The entire setup is a test setup. So Nginx might be the way to go, but how will it affect the performance of webHDFS?

Comment: 1. you can't reasonably use "test setup" and "performance" in the same sentence -- and nowadays it's hard to avoid passing thru 2+ levels of VIP, LB, Kubernetes ingress, nginx sidecar etc. before reaching the web service -- but indeed a proxy will have side effects, especially in the max size of HTTP payloads -- also be aware that WebHDFS has a peculiar way of responding HTTP 30x when you upload a file (that's the way the NameNode redirects the load to a specific DataNode) and it might trigger a double upload to the proxy if your web client does not react appropriately

Comment: 2. again, enabling Kerberos auth in Hadoop has MASSIVE side effects on every service and every client -- it's not something you switch on as an afterthought, rather a full migration project _per se_ -- and beware, you can't rollback from that in practise.

Comment: 3. there is no way you can mock up Kerberos auth, it goes too deep into every Hadoop service

Comment: Got it, thanks for this insight! I think I'll stick to using a reverse proxy. Setting up Kerberos seems like it would be pretty involved, which is what I was trying to avoid in the first place!